# jQuery / Javascript - Set div height to largest element height in that row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a row that contains 4 products, just like the example below (in the example I've only included 1 product, just repeat `<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3'>` 3 more times within `<div class="row">`):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3'>
      <div class='thumbnail'>
        <div class = 'matchHeight'><a href='www.url.com'><img src='product.jpg' alt='product'></a></div>
        <div class='caption' style = 'text-align: center;'>
          <div style = 'height: 60px;'>Product Name<br />
            £9.99</div>
          <p style = 'padding-top: 10px;'><a href='www.url.com' class='btn btn-primary btn-thumbp' role='button'>View</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

The following jQuery calculates the height of each 'matchHeight' div, gets the tallest and then sets each div to the same height:

```
boxes = $('.matchHeight');
maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
Math, boxes.map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get());
boxes.height(maxHeight);
```

My page has multiple `<div class="row">` elements.  Is it possible to get the function above to run for each row? I want each row to act independantly.  I don't want a product in row 6 to affect row 2 for example.

Comment: Loop over each `.row`, and inside of there find the `.matchHeight` elements and set the `maxHeight`

Comment: http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc credits goes to  => [Micah Godbolt](http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/) **responsive version**

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try below JS code:

```
$('.row').each(function(){
  boxes = $(this).find('.matchHeight');
  maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
  Math, boxes.map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
  }).get());
  boxes.height(maxHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the answer code here but updated to make it a bit neater and more efficient. Someone in my team tried to use this as it was in the codePen and I had to clean it up for production, so just saving future users the hassle:

JS:

```
var equalheight = function (container) {
    var elems = $(container).children();
    if (elems.length) {
        var currentTallest = 0,
            currentRow,
            row;

        elems.each(function () {
            var $el = $(this);
            var topPosition = $el.position().top;
            $el.height('auto');

            if (currentRow != topPosition) {
                //if we ran any elements already, set their height
                row && row.length && row.height(currentTallest);

                //reset the current row, tallest height and remove all elements from 'row'
                row = $el, currentRow = topPosition, currentTallest = $el.height();
            } else {
                //if we are still on the same row, add this element to the row and test its height
                row = row.add($el);
                currentTallest = currentTallest < $el.height() ? $el.height() : currentTallest;
            }
            //set the height if we have more than 1 element, otherwise it will already be the correct height
            if (row.length > 1) {
                row.height(currentTallest);
            }
        });
    }
};

equalheight($('.equal-height'))
```

Html:

```
<div class="equal-height">
    <div class="child-to-resize-1"></div>
    <div class="child-to-resize-2"></div>
    <div class="child-to-resize-3"></div>
</div>
```